# What happens if a gTLD fails to pay ICANN in time?

Tags: top-level-domains, icann

Do I threaten to loose a domain if a new gTLD stops paying ICANN?  I'm no expert but similar to how we have paid yearly renewal, the people providing gTLDs must also pay renewal fees.

Comment: We've go two related questions [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76747/my-domain-registrar-has-gone-bankrupt-but-the-domain-is-locked-what-can-i-do) and [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/64741/what-happens-to-my-domain-if-the-tld-fails?rq=1), but if you're asking what happens if the Registry or Registrar fails to pay the ICANN fees for each domain, I suppose that would be somewhat different. If not, and what you're asking is the same as one of those questions, let me know.

Comment: The owners of gTLDs have to make such a large investment in hardware and network infrastructure that renewing the gTLD is small potatoes. As well, the money a gTLD can make in just one day is staggering.

Comment: @dan I think the second is a duplicate although the answer isn't great, but it does seem to answer my main question partially.  I have marked it as duplicate.

Comment: @LiamWilliam Thanks for marking it, that's the first time I've seen someone do that on their own post (voluntarily) :-)